# GitHub Pull Request - Status Check Title

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, pull-request

I recently started using the Github Pull Request Plugin on Jenkins and notice on the PR it says default - build passed or failed.

Does anyone know where the label default is getting generated from? I looked through the configuration on Jenkins but was not able to see where it is pulling that from.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rCqH.png)

Comment: Usually it reflects the user name from the credentials that have been used in "SCM section" of jenkins jobs (i.e) username/password used to checkout the code.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought too. Don't see anything that relates to that though..